# Laravel Sanctum returns 500 when trying to access sanctum protected API

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, laravel-sanctum, laravel-airlock

I am using Laravel 8.12 with PostgreSQL. I am trying to use Laravel Sanctum as authentication for my API. This is the schema for sanctum:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreatePersonalAccessTokensTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('personal_access_tokens', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary()->default(new Expression("uuid_generate_v4()"));
            $table->uuidMorphs('tokenable');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('token', 64)->unique();
            $table->text('abilities')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('last_used_at')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('personal_access_tokens');
    }
}
```

And this is my user table:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary()->default(new Expression('uuid_generate_v4()'));
            $table->string('first_name', 255);
            $table->string('last_name', 255);
            $table->string('email', 255)->index()->unique();
            $table->string('password', 100);
            $table->boolean('email_verified')->default(false);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

Now, when I try to send the token in headers, I get this error: `SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type uuid: \"0\" (SQL: select * from \"personal_access_tokens\" where \"personal_access_tokens\".\"id\" = 0 limit 1)`. As from my viewpoint, it looks as if this is the error with column type being uuid?

This is the command I use to make request:

```
curl --request GET \
  --url http://127.0.0.1:3001/api/user \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer 0|s0Vpci4xXoEJh1HMEihNd65GLvDmINILaiJr8o8e' \
  --header 'Content-type: application/json'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create a file with following contents.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Laravel\Sanctum\PersonalAccessToken as SanctumPersonalAccessToken;

class PersonalAccessToken extends SanctumPersonalAccessToken
{
    public $incrementing = true;

    protected $primaryKey = "id";
    protected $keyType = "string";
}
```

and then I am calling this file `PersonalAccessToken`. And then on `AppServiceProvider`, do something like this.

am calling this file PersonalAccessToken. And then on AppServiceProvider, do something like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Models\PersonalAccessToken;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Laravel\Sanctum\Sanctum;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        Sanctum::ignoreMigrations();
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Sanctum::usePersonalAccessTokenModel(PersonalAccessToken::class);
    }
}
```

this will solve your problem